# The number of times the count is displayed is equal to the value of the count.Ms Access vba 2007

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am working on an MS ACCESS 2007 application. I made a query where I count the number of rows which have a particular "ID". This count is calculated and stored in a column in the same query. This count is stored against another column which is unique and which is related to the column "ID". Hence the count is not repeated in the query.However, when I display this count in a text box along with other related values, the count is repeated the times equal to its value.
I tried using Dlookup() and DCount() with no different results.
I hope someone can help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Your question is hard to follow. Can you include the SQL for the query, table definitions, and expected output?

Comment: It's still a little confusing, are you using a bound "continuous form" by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use DCount() to count the number of rows with a particular ID?
In your Form code you'd have the following VBA to assing the number of records in MyTable with Id = 5.

```
CountTextBox.Text = DCount("Id", "MyTable", "Id = 5")
```

This is the same as saying

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) 
FROM MyTable
WHERE Id = 5
```

If I understand what you're saying, it sounds like you might be storing the number of records with Id = 5 against each record with ID = 5.  If that's the case you can use DFirst("IdCount", "MyTable", "Id = 5") to get the first record of ID = 5 and read the count only from that record, as it'll be the same for all ID = 5.  Seems a bit weird though.

Sorry if I misunderstood your question. I find it hard to follow.

Comment: I did try DCount() and the column is tbl1.ID which is unique.So, there are no multiple records.However the problem is different.I have the recordsource of the form to display some columns related to the tbl2.ID.There are multiple tbl2.ID for each tbl1.ID.So each row displays the same count value.